# android changing button colors turns button orange when clicking... why?

Tags: java, android, button, colors

I've got some buttons that I want to change background colors upon clicking.  As a quiz app, they'll turn red if the wrong one is clicked and green if the right one is clicked.  I also wanted to reset the buttons back to default when the question is switched to repeat the process of selecting an answer.

My problem is when I went to implement:

```
buttonOne.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
buttonTwo.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
buttonThree.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
buttonFour.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
```

Which is supposed to reset the buttons back to default (right?).  Now, when I click the buttons and hold them down the background is orange, and I have no idea why.  Anyone know why this is?

I haven't set anything to orange so it seems quite random.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a collaboratively edited site.  Questions you post are not yours, *per se*.  More experienced members of the community can and will edit your questions to improve them.  Please do not get into "rollback wars" with people trying to improve your question.  If I had to guess, although the edit seemed minor, it's possible that the extra space you had in your code was causing it to scroll on small browser screens, making it harder to read.

Comment: Gotchya, and there was no "rollback war".  Though that seems to be what you're instigating by editing the post to remove the question that you answered.  Way to dip your hands in the cookie jar.  Next time I have a question I'll just submit it to you and you can ask it how you see fit.

Comment: Seasoned users edit questions to remove unnecessary clutter as well as inflammatory comments. Drop the attitude.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the resource you're using is a set of drawables which has an "active" one set, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bar_bottom_home_active" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bar_bottom_home"/>

</selector>
```

That would explain different colour when you hold down the button.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I just found that code somewhere and it technically did what I wanted.  It removed the green/red background.  How else would I go about it to return a button to the actual default look/drawables upon activity startup?  Is there a way I can find out what the current default is for my project/version?

Comment: Hmm... Tbh I'm not entirely sure atm (quite tired, sorry). What I'd do is I'd set your own look of all the Buttons because you don't really know what a default Button is going to look like on different flavours of the OS, e.g. a HTC version could be blue and a Samsung one -- grey.

Comment: Gotchya, makes sense.  Know of a good resource to tell me how many/what drawable's I need to create to override the current ones?

Comment: Basically, whatever you set yourself will look like you set it and all the rest will default to what's on the device. I think the best thing is to just try it out on a few different flavours/versions of Android. Let me know if that answers your question - I might've not understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it this way:

```
buttonOne.setBackgroundColor(YOUR_COLOR_HERE);
```

In the color it's prefered to add it to your colors' xml file and refer to it

Comment: I'm sorry I guess I wasn't clear.  My issue isn't that I want to change the background colors.  That part works fine.  My issue is that only after implementing the code above (set background resource to default), the buttons now turn orange during the clicking action.  But they still turn green or red as desired once the button is released.  I know it's petty, but I want to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create an xml file. For example:

- Create colors.xml in res->values
- Put colors code in this xml

```html
<color name="orange">#FF9900</color>
<color name="green">#009900</color>
<color name="blue">#000099</color>
<color name="red">#bf360c</color>
```

- Now, you can use the colors.

  ```
  buttonOne.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
  ```